# Way to put more focus on certain div for Mac VoiceOver?

Tags: macos, voiceover

I work for a newspaper and we got a call from someone who uses Mac VoiceOver. He said beginning a few days ago VoiceOver no longer reads the articles on our site correctly. I've tested it with my extremely limited VoiceOver understanding and I can't get it to read the body of the story at all. It might read the lede but it just stops after that.

So is there a way to place a higher VO priority in the HTML? There are so many other elements on the page that are being read before VO even gets to the body of the article.

Here is an example page if it will help anyone figure out why it isn't reading the main body:
http://www.thebrunswicknews.com/news/national_news/professor-historic-outhouses-underappreciated-in-southwest/article_a4319478-fe98-5dd1-9c98-ebabde4ee856.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TabIndex is used on this page.  This is creating a navigation trap.  For example, in the form with the heading "Welcome to the Discussion" there are two input fields with tab index of 100, and 101 respectively.  This suggests to me that there are at least 99 other controls with tab index on them.  This in itself is an accessibility violation, as the focus order, vs the content order is out of sync, and doesn't make sense.  TabIndex (except a tab index of 0) should be used very cautiously, especially when it comes to accessibility!

Now, usually, we would be able to rely on VoiceOver arrow key navigation, to navigate to content elements, rather than active focusable controls, with tabbed navigation.  HOWEVER, most of these tab indexed controls are within form elements, and so a different navigation mode takes over, and disables your typical arrow key, VoiceOver navigation.  As such, users cannot (without a pretty deep knowledge of how to use VoiceOver/the weird structure of this page) escape from this.  As such, what you have is a large keyboard trap, bouncing around approximately 101 different elements on your page.  Set all tab index values to 0, or simply remove them, unless they're on elements that aren't usually focusable, and you should be good to go!  Or at the very least, the issue that you're talking about will be fixed.  There are a lot of other accessibility issues on this page, but fixing this is a good start.

Comment: So if I get my content management system to add a tabindex="10" to the div that contains the main body of the article that should work? I tested it and it seems like that did it, I just want to get your opinion since you seem to know a lot about VoiceOver. Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: This will fix THIS particular problem.  But you likely still have a keyboard trap somewhere.  What you want to do is set ALL tabindex properties to 0, and just allow the browser to figure out the proper ordering based on order of elements in the dom.